# Electron - intercept all renderer process requests and add additional headers

Tags: javascript, electron

How can I intercept all HTTP(S) requests made from the renderer process and add an additional header parameter to them?

For the main process, there is the `session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` API available. However, I am unable to find a similar API for requests initiated from the renderer process.

Answer (score 2):

Look at: [atom_api_web_request.cc](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/29501dbd01953208e5cb90c1e07730c6cdabc8b0/atom/browser/api/atom_api_web_request.cc#L117) for your requested method.

Usage example:

```
   win.webContents.session.webRequest.onHeadersReceived({}, (res, cb) => {
    if(res.responseHeaders['x-frame-options'] || res.responseHeaders['X-Frame-Options']){
      delete res.responseHeaders['x-frame-options'];
      delete res.responseHeaders['X-Frame-Options'];
    }
    cb({cancel: false, responseHeaders: res.responseHeaders});
  });
```

you can change the listener method to: '**onSendHeaders**' / '**onBeforeSendHeaders**' if that is what you need.